# Is there an API or function to block the automatic scrolling that happens when space and arrows are pressed?

Tags: javascript, scroll, keypress

I'm making a keypress based app and wondering if I could do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event.preventDefault() on the `keypress` event of the body.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83p4b/).

Scrolling (using the spacebar) should not work in the HTML area.